# Linq expression with multiple input parameters

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I wrote the following code and I'm not able to understand how it is executed.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] nums = { 1, 5, 10, 3, 554, 34};
        var nn = nums.TakeWhile((n, junk) => n > junk);
        nn.Count();
        foreach (var a in nn)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

First I wrote the TakeWhile expression as `n => n > 5`. I'm able to understand that. But I just added one more parameter `junk`. What is junk here? What value is assigned to it during query exeution? How is it giving the output as 1, 5 and 10.

Comment: My bad. Was expecting a table in MSDN with each and every overload explained with each and every parameter. Din't read those lines you guys quoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`junk` is the index of of the currently processed element - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548775.aspx

Much more readable and understable would be

```
var nn = nums.TakeWhile((n, index) => n > index);
```

Comment: Seems kind of an odd predicate as well, "take while the value is greater than the index"

Comment: yeah but this general form of including the index as a parameter has its uses... imagine a situation where you need to take to position of the element into account for a more complex condition...

Comment: Yeah i agree it has its uses, even that this use my be valid and i just don't know what the reason is, it just seems a bit odd.

Answer (score 3):

`junk` is the index. So what you're iterating over is:

```
(1, 0)  => true
(5, 1)  => true
(10, 2) => true
(3, 3)  => false => abort
```

The method signature you're using is:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeWhile<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate
)
```

> *predicate*
>   Type: `System.Func(Of TSource, Int32, Boolean)`
>   A function to test each source element for a condition; **the second parameter of the function represents the index of the source element.**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548775.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try using the "correct" names: `var nn = nums.TakeWhile((n, index) => n > index);` and it will be clear!

From the [TakeWhile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548775.aspx) page: `predicate
Type: System.Func<TSource, Int32, Boolean>
A function to test each source element for a condition;` **`the second parameter of the function represents the index of the source element.`**

Comment: Didn't even know what the second paramater is. That's my question. So naming it correctly without knowing is not possible. As I said I missed those quoted lines from MSDN. Was expecting a overload methods table with all its parameters explained :).

Comment: @NLV If you are using Visual Studio, write `nums.TakeWhile(` and press the down arrow to see the second overload. The description you'll get is `predicate: A function to test each source element for a condition; the second parameter of the function represents the index of the source element.` (and the "correct" names was a joke... The point is that the "right" name was the explanation :-) )